# PowerMock PrepareForTest annotation causing problems with AmazonSQSClient constructor

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, powermock

I'm having some trouble with the [PrepareForTest](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.5/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html) annotation and creating a new instance of an AmazonSQSClient.

I'm writing a Jenkins plugin and unfortunately need to mock the [FormValidation](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/util/FormValidation.html) static class in order to ensure that warning and error messages are produced on field validation of my plugin. However when creating an instance of `AmazonSQSClient` I get an `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException`

I've abstracted it down to a very simple example, here's my test file:

```
package com.test;

import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)  
public class SQSTest {

    // This is for mimicking the mocking of FormValidation
    private static class Foo {}

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(Foo.class)
    public void buildTest()
    {
        AmazonSQS sqs = new AmazonSQSClient();
    }
}
```

On running this code I get the following error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Failure initializing default SSL context
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:93)
    at com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createPoolingClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:26)
    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:66)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.<init>(AmazonSQSClient.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.<init>(AmazonSQSClient.java:93)
    at com.test.SQSTest.buildTest(SQSTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.checkSuperClass(GetInstance.java:258)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:237)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:358)
    ... 42 more
```

In order to help anyone wanting to build and run this quickly here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test.sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>hpi</packaging>



    <properties>
        <!--
          explicitly specifying the latest version here because one we get from the parent POM
          tends to lag behind a bit
        -->
        <maven-hpi-plugin.version>1.96</maven-hpi-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When the annotation `@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)` is removed from the method the test runs fine.

I was wondering if someone could explain why this is happening and if there is a work around for it or a way to avoid mocking the `FormValidation` class?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sarah, Were you able to finally get rid if this error? I am facing the same problem right now, unable to find much help online on this.

Answer (score 17):

Try to add `@PowerMockIgnore("org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*")` annotation to your class

Comment: Hi I am having the same problem as Sarah.

I tried adding the annotion you suggest and I get:

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to access default SSL context
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext not a SSLContext

Comment: The above didn't work. I think I need to ignore other packages too. I decided to move this test into another class without using PowerMock.

Answer (score 9):

As @Natalie already mentioned, you can work with the `@PowerMockIgnore()` annotation. Maybe you need to ignore the packages `javax.net.ssl.*` and / or `javax.crypto.*`:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*", "javax.net.ssl.*" , "javax.crypto.*"})
```

You can get here some background information:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/v4nreP2AnOQ

> This is most likely because SSLContext is loaded by the bootstrap classloader and PowerMock cannot byte-code manipulate these classes. You have to use this approach to mock that method.
>     /Johan Haleby

Comment: This list of ignore covers it all! Thanks!