# Issue with PowerMock - Spring

Tags: powermock

I am trying to test my CXF web-service - which has in-interceptors and it has the task to modify the JSON received from UI and pass it to a 3rd Party Rest Service.
I am mostly using EasyMock, but since I have to mock the Http rest call too, and the code uses the **static class** org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients, So I am going for PowerMock along with EasyMock.

---

But I am facing an issue of similar kind like this: [PowerMock PrepareForTest annotation causing problems with AmazonSQSClient constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385074/powermock-preparefortest-annotation-causing-problems-with-amazonsqsclient-constr)

---

Following the solution I have added the

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.apache.cxf.jaxws.*,sun.security.ssl.*,org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.*" })
```

Still the issue is not getting resolved. I want to understand which packages do I need to include to get rid of this. The error stack trace is:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '*.*': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig] while setting bean property 'tlsClientParameters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.TLSClientParametersType) throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException,java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:154)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.invokeService(Unknown Source)
at com.uhg.pdr.consumer.SelectProfessionalsByIdTypeConsumer.invokeService(SelectProfessionalsByIdTypeConsumer.java:72)
at com.uhg.pdr.providerinfo.SelectProfessionalsByIdTypeProvider.getAssociatedProviders(SelectProfessionalsByIdTypeProvider.java:212)
at com.uhg.util.rest.PropelUtil.getProvidersByMpin(PropelUtil.java:212)
at com.uhg.pdr.interceptor.service.MppBaseInterceptorServiceImpl.getProviders(MppBaseInterceptorServiceImpl.java:302)
at com.uhg.pdr.interceptor.MppBaseInterceptor.handleMessage(MppBaseInterceptor.java:79)
at com.uhg.pdr.bundling.transactions.ProviderLanguageTransactionTest.handleMessageTest(ProviderLanguageTransactionTest.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:148)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:140)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:140)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
      Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '*.*': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig] while setting bean property 'tlsClientParameters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.TLSClientParametersType) throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException,java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.configureBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:314)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport.configureBean(BeanConfigurerSupport.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureBean(ConfigurerImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureWithWildCard(ConfigurerImpl.java:176)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureBean(ConfigurerImpl.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring.ConfigurerImpl.configureBean(ConfigurerImpl.java:115)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.configure(HTTPTransportFactory.java:187)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getConduit(HTTPTransportFactory.java:270)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:239)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:246)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:63)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:851)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:526)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.TLSClientParametersType) throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException,java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(org.apache.cxf.configuration.security.TLSClientParametersType) throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException,java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
... 70 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyManagerFactory: sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509 not a KeyManagerFactory
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.checkSuperClass(GetInstance.java:258)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:237)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.java:139)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSParameterJaxBUtils.getKeyManagers(TLSParameterJaxBUtils.java:274)
at org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(TLSClientParametersConfig.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149)
... 71 more
```

---

Here is my Test class :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ProviderAddressUpdateController.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.apache.cxf.jaxws.*,sun.security.ssl.*,org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.*" })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context-test.xml" })
public class ProviderLanguageTransactionTest {
  .....
  .....
  .....
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    .....
    .....
  }
  @Test
  public void handleMessageTest() throws Exception {
    ....
    ....
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved by adding @PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.net.ssl.*" })
Also the class inside @PrepareForTest annotation should be the class mocked by PowerMock - not the controller. If you are mocking the HttpClients class,then you should write @PrepareForTest(HttpClients.class) before that method inside which you are mocking.